# How to prevent gerrit push to authoritative repository

Tags: gerrit

We've been using gerrit for a few years, but we don't use the workflow described in the gerrit documentation. The developers who drove the adoption of gerrit and manaaged it for us are no longer here, unfortunately, so we have no local experts. We don't clone from gerrit, but instead clone from our authoratitive repository and have a 'gerrit' remote specified in our clones. Recently we had a user use the command:

```
git push gerrit master;refs/for/master/some_comment
```

Since the ';' terminated the command it became just

```
git push gerrit master
```

which actually pushed the commit to the master branch of the authoratative repository. However, it did so without executing the pre-recevie hook (or any hooks as near as I can tell) in the authoratative repository. We have two questions:

1. Is there a way to tell gerrit to reject this type of push? I tried setting the project to Read-only, but that also rejects correctly formatted change pushes.
2. If not, can we ensure that the hooks in the authoritative repository get executed?

Comment: I don't fully understand the setup that you're describing.  If the remote named `gerrit` is the Gerrit server, how did `git push gerrit` cause the commit to be pushed to the 'authoratitive repository?

Answer (score 1):

To prevent direct pushes into the repository, remove the `Push` permission from `refs/heads/*` in the project's access controls.

The `Push` permission should remain on `refs/for/refs/heads/*` to allow developers to push changes for review.